# Император принял руководство войсками и выехал в Ставку [ставку?] в Могилеве

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

В интернете встречается двоякое написание: и с прописной, и со строчной. (http://www.pravenc.ru/search/?text=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2+%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

- В ходе первой мировой войны при **Ставке** верховного главнокомандующего...
- В 1943 (…) было связано с расположением здесь **Ставки** имп. Николая II.
- ...вел. кн. Василий остановился в монастыре, устроив здесь **ставку**.
- В окт. Ж. приехал к императору в **Ставку** в Могилев с чудотворной Казанской Песчанской иконой.
- ...в Белую Церковь, где находилась **ставка** короля.

## Как все-таки правильно написать слово "ставка"?

Answer (score 1):

**В ходе первой мировой войны при Ставке верховного главнокомандующего ...**

Здесь "верховного" должно писаться с прописной, я думаю.

"Орфографический словарь" на сайте Грамота.ру говорит следующее:

> ставка, -и, р. мн. -вок и (высший орган руководства вооруженными
>   силами во время войны) Ставка, -и

Следовательно, если речь идёт только о месте расположения, тогда "ставка" со строчной, а если используется полное или сокращённое название "высшего органа руководства" (ср. Генеральный штаб), тогда с прописной.

Собственно по вопросу: "выехал в ставку" должно писаться со строчной.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как вы поняли, что в вопросе идет речь только о месте расположения? Может, там используется сокращенное название "высшего органа руководства" с указанием  место его расположения (в Могилеве)?

Comment: @Юлия Не знаю, что-то у меня язык не поворачивается сказать **выехал** в "высший орган руководства". **Въехать** разве что можно (на белом коне :)